# GREP: interactive vs crontab

Tags: bash, grep, cron

I have a simple text file I am monitoring for change using a BASH script.
The text I am looking for may begin at the start of a line or offset by spaces.
My search is pretty simple;

```
#!/bin/bash
value=`/bin/grep "^\s*mystring:" mytextfile`
echo "found: [$value]" >> myoutput.log
```

This works just fine when run on the command line, but does not work if called from a script configured in crontab.  I have a workaround for my problem, but still can not explain why using the caret (^) and space (\s*) characters together when calling grep from within crontab?

Altering PATH and environment don't seem to have any affect.  Any ideas?

***... thanks for the comments!***

1. path to grep was consistent
2. same script was called from the command line as was configured in crontab

Solution was to use the syntax;

```
value=`/bin/grep -E '^[[:space:]]*mystring:' myfile`
```

Needed a combination of 3 things;

1. single quotes when using regex
2. grep -E    !extended regular expression
3. [[:space:]] instead of \s for space character

I'm still not sure why the [[:space:]] worked when \s doesn't in crontab, when it works interactively.

Comment: How is it failing?  What are you doing with the output?  Can you show us the complete configuration (crontab + script) and let us know what you're trying to do?

Comment: You should not use `\s`. Use `[[:space:]]` instead, and single-quote your expressions: `/bin/grep -E '^[[:space:]]*mystring' mytextfile`

Comment: Are you using `/bin/grep` in both places? Most likely you're using a later version of grep in shell script and that supports regex by default.

Comment: Is mytestfile specified as a global path? or relative to something?

Comment: I had tried [[:space:]] but not with -E.   :)

Comment: you can post your answer and accept it after (24?) hrs to gain reputation points. Nice first post. Good luck.

Comment: You may need to provide the full path to 'myfile'

Answer (score 0):

If you can run these commands from inside a shell script at the command-line and it works, but not in crontab, then my guess is that the default SHELL variable of crontab is not set to the same shell as the one you use at the command-line. Would this be the case?

You can check the default at /etc/crontab, or you can force it in the crontab itself (above the schedules) the same way:

SHELL=/bin/bash

Mine is set to /bin/bash, and I was able to use your script as is like this:

- Created /tmp/test.sh with your code in it
- Created /tmp/mytextfile with the line "     mystring:" in it, followed by more test lines of random characters.
- Created the following entry in my crontab: `*/1 * * * * (cd /tmp; /bin/bash test.sh)`
- Tailed the file myoutput.log and waited 1 minute.

The line `found: [     mystring:]` showed up every minute. So it worked.

I'm running CentOS 6.2

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't work for me.  I am using CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
I have SHELL=/bin/bash in my crontab but the line I was using was;

*/1 * * * * root (cd /tmp; /bin/bash /tmp/test.sh)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I use grep for regex, I try to make sure to include a flag that tells it to process regular expressions, or run "egrep" which does the same thing.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. AFAIK, `grep` always searches for regular expressions; its name is a contraction of `g/re/p`, an `ed` command to 'globally search for `re` and print'. The only issue is which dialect of regular expression it uses, which you control with the `-E` (extended regular expression) or `-F` (fixed strings) flags (or neither for basic regular expressions). But they're all regular expressions. (Some versions of `grep` support PCRE — Perl compatible regular expressions too.)

Comment: Well there's different kinds of (standards) for regular expressions, and you can tell grep which one you would like to adhere to. So that's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if a bit late to the party... I just found a very similar problem with `egrep` after years of using the very same script flawlessly.

It turned out a `LANG` environment variable problem. If I egrep for, say, 'blablabla', it works fine both in the console and in a crontab. However, if I search for 'blablablá' it fails in the latter but not in the former (I use everywhere Latin1 encoding).

`printenv` in crontab gave me `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, while in the console I have no `LANG` env variable set. Therefore, the solution was to add `LANG=""` to my crontab file. Problem solved.

I have no clue why it suddenly changed. Maybe an update in `crontab` or in `grep`?

So, I would look at an env variable problem. Others also suggested this, with other variables.